# Change field names associated with sort order and search filter in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using `LazyDataModel` in Primefaces. Therefore, the fields associated with sort order and search filter can be obtained in the overloaded `load()` method of `LazyDataModel<T>` along with other parameters.

```
@Override
public List<StateTable> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, String> filters)
{

}
```

So, if I had a column like,

```
<p:column 
         headerText="Country" 
         resizable="false" 
         sortBy="#{state.country.countryName}" 
         filterBy="#{state.country.countryName}" 
         filterMaxLength="45">

         ...

</p:column>
```

In this case, the field name which is available in the `multiSortMeta` and the `filters` parameters of the `load()` method as mentioned previously would be `country.countryName`.

---

I'm doing sorting and filtering on country name (and not on country id). The country name is by the way available in the other table (the parent table of the `state` table). In that table, the actual column name is `country_name` which is mapped by the name `countryName` in its persistence entity class.

Therefore, actual field name `country.countryName` supplied needs to be replaced by `countryName`.

Replacing this name requires conditional checks while iterating over the `Map<String, String>` and/or the `List<SortMeta>` which is tedious especially when there are more such nested properties.

I'm looking for a way to precisely change this name to a desired field name as and when required. Does `Primefaces` support such features in `<p:column>` or somewhere else?

P.S. It is Primefaces 3.5.

Comment: *"Therefore, actual field name countryId.countryName supplied needs to be replaced by countryName."* I do not understand the why. Please elaborate. By the way, it's strange to see a "country ID" to *have* a country name as well. Shouldn't `countryId` property better be renamed to `country`? And `countryName` to `name`? It's also strange to see the country name being duplicated in the DB model. Wouldn't you rather use a FK on ID of country table?

Comment: @BalusC : Sorry, `countryId` actually refers to `country` as you mentioned. These property names were generated by the IDE and I didn't bother to change them and yes there is a foreign key on the `state` table that references to the primary key of the `country` table. I'm doing sorting and filtering on `countryName` which is available in the `country` table. Therefore, sorting and filtering requires either a subquery or a join with `countryName` (and not `country.countryName`) in the `WHERE` and/or `ORDER BY` clause(s).

Comment: The field name supplied by Primefaces , `country.countryName` can not be used in the JPA criteria query. The field name should be `countryName` and not `country.countryName`.